# Remove vector element with %in% returns character(0)

Tags: r

Got a quick question. I'm trying to remove a vector element with the code below. But I get `character(0)` returned instead of the rest of the vector elements.

What have I done wrong?

```
> str(ticker.names)
 chr [1:10] "AAK.ST" "ABB.ST" "ALFA.ST" "ALIV-SDB.ST" "AOI.ST" "ASSA-B.ST" "ATCO-A.ST" "ATCO-B.ST" "AXFO.ST" "AXIS.ST"
> ticker.names[! 'AAK.ST' %in% ticker.names]
character(0)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we need to remove the elements in `ticker.names' that are not 'AAK.ST'.

```
ticker.names[!ticker.names %in% 'AAK.ST']
```

Or use `setdiff`

```
setdiff(ticker.names, 'AAK.ST')
```

---

Consider the approach OP is using,

```
'AAK.ST' %in% ticker.names
#[1] TRUE
ticker.names['AAK.ST' %in% ticker.names]
#[1] "AAK.ST"  "ABB.ST"  "ALFA.ST"
```

By negating,

```
!'AAK.ST' %in% ticker.names
#[1] FALSE

ticker.names[!'AAK.ST' %in% ticker.names]
#character(0)
```

In the former case, the `TRUE` is recycled to the length of the 'ticker.names', so all the elements of the vector are returned, while in the latter, the `FALSE` gets recycled and no elements are returned.

#### data

```
ticker.names <- c('AAK.ST', 'ABB.ST', 'ALFA.ST')
```